# Show that $\bigg| \int_{[-1,1]} t^{\frac{1}{3}}f(t)d\lambda(x) \bigg|^3\leq \frac{16}{9} \int_{[-1,1]}|f(t)|^3 d\lambda(t)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**Problem:**
Show that  $$\bigg| \int_{[-1,1]} t^{\frac{1}{3}}f(t)d\lambda (t) \bigg|^3\leq \frac{16}{9} \int_{[-1,1]}|f(t)|^3 d\lambda (t)$$

for all $f\in \mathscr{L}^3([-1,1],\lambda).$

**Attempt:**
I know i have to use Hölder's Inequality, but i have no idea how to use it because $f\in \mathscr{L}^3([-1,1],\lambda),$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, that means $t^{\frac{1}{3}}\in \mathscr{L}^{\frac{3}{2}}([-1,1],\lambda)$ but that can't be true?

Any hints?
(No answers.)

Comment: Why not? $(|t|^{1/3})^{3/2}=|t|^{1/2}\in L_1[-1.1]$.